# Cannot web scrape text from div

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I tried scraping printing text from div and get error as shown below! please help

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= '/Users/leah/Documents/Scrape-Finantials/webdrivers/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.dummy-id.com/StockInfo/_ScreenerScan.html?SYMBOLS_PP=25&SYMBOLS_ONLY=on&sort1=MaxVWVP&sort2=None&sort3=None&WN=Lowfloat&MaxFloat=20000000&XN=on&X_NYSE=on&X_ARCA=on')

ticker = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div')
len(ticker)

print(ticker.text)

#Try printing ticker and get following error!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-0ca4276d61ba> in <module>
----> 1 print(ticker.text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `find_elements_by_xpath()` will get a list of elements, not a single element. Calling len(ticker) is fine, but ticker.text is not correct.

if you want to print each single element, you need a loop

```
ticker = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div')
len(ticker)
for elem in ticker:
  print(elem.text)
```

Reference: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Thanks very much